# Hibernate why are my objects becoming detached?

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary

```
Map<String, Type> myMap = new HashMap<String, Type>();

Query query = session.createQuery("" +
        "SELECT a " +
        "FROM Articulo a ");
List<Object> list = query.list();

// Add all query elements to the hashmap
for (Object entrada : lista) {
    myMap.put(entrada.getKey(), (Type) entrada);
// Type someOtherObject = entrada.getReferencedProperty();
}

Type someObject = (Type) myMap.get("someValidKey").getReferencedProperty(); //normal getter
```

Here `someObject` comes out `null` and the object is detached. However if I uncomment the `someOtherObject` line. relationship is fetched correctly.

What is going on?

Comment: Are these actually in the same method? That distinction is very important. I am guessing not, since `codLineas` is not defined anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @rmlan sorry, I was simplifying the code and I missed that. I edited it now. The code is all part of the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Deeper in my code, I had a call to session.clear(). That was causing all my entities to be detached.

Comment: encountered the same!, `session.clear()` was called in a 'flushService' that was explicitly flushing entities

Answer (score 3):

I don't see your whole codebase but in **95%** of the cases your objects get detached because you leave the transaction context (or you are not in a transaction in the first place).

From a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260297/how-does-the-detached-object-work-in-hibernate):

> As soon as the session used to save, load, get or find an entity has been closed, the entity becomes detached. This means that it's not connected anymore to a session, and works like any other POJO.

Comment: I am not closing the session explicitly. Is there any reason why it would close automatically?

Comment: Or it is in transaction but `ReferenceProperty` is complex object and cannot be initialized by default. See `fetch-type EAGER/LAZY`. Btw `entrada.getReferencedProperty();` in loop  could make other queries and therefore you see that object is attached.

Comment: Are you using `@Transactional`? You need to show us more code in order to help you further.