# Spring JPA get error detached entity passed to persist on unidirectional OneToOne relationship when save to repository without cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity: Person and Patient. The Patient is a child of Person and it maps its primary key to Person's primary key. This was meant to be a unidirectional OneToOne relation so Person doesn't know about Patient.

The Person is already persisted in the PostgreSQL, but when I tried to persist the Patient, I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.clinic.entities.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.clinic.entities.Person
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy89.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.clinic.ClinicApplication.lambda$demo$0(ClinicApplication.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

This is a snippet of my Person Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;
}
```

The Patient class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "last_visit")
    private Date lastVisit;
}
```

the Patient repo:

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Long> {
    Patient findById(long id);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Patient p WHERE p.person.email = ?1")
    Patient findByEmail(String email);
}
```

EDIT:

Here is where I tried to save the Patient

```
Person person = new Person("patient", "pat", "patient@email.com");
personRepository.save(person);
Patient patient1 = new Patient(person);
patientRepository.save(patient1); // <---- here is the exception happen
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are calling save?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260297/how-does-the-detached-object-work-in-hibernate

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Sorry, I've edited the post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that person is detached after save because you obviously don't have an outer transaction to keep the entity managed.

So you have to add an outer transaction to have this in one transaction:

```
@Transactional
public void yourSaveMethod() {
    Person person = new Person("patient", "pat", "patient@email.com");
    personRepository.save(person);
    Patient patient1 = new Patient(person);
    patientRepository.save(patient1);
}
```